# Detect sequences of ordered strings and group them using R

Tags: r, string, sequence

I have a string vector with about 500K elements in it and I want to assign a value to each of the element to show the group number of each element.

The grouping criteria goes like this:

- a group number is assigned consecutively from the top of the list
- Each element should be assigned different groups unless if a minimum of 3 consecutive elements are in ascending alphabetical order, in which these consecutive elements will be in one group.

How do I do this in R?

For example and expected output:

```
> my_strings <- c("xx1", "1xxx", "abc.xyz", "a", "ad022", "ghj1", "kf1", "991r",
+                 "jdd", "12vd", "r34o", "z", "034mh")
> expected_output <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8)
> (df <- data.frame(input = my_strings, output = expected_output))
     input output
1      xx1      1
2     1xxx      2
3  abc.xyz      3
4        a      4
5    ad022      4
6     ghj1      4
7      kf1      4
8     991r      5
9      jdd      6
10    12vd      7
11    r34o      7
12       z      7
13   034mh      8
```

So far, I attempt to use `dplyr::lead` and assign order based on two consecutive elements. I don't know how to proceed from here though.

```
res <- as_tibble(my_strings) %>%
  mutate(after = lead(my_strings))
res$pre_group = apply(res, 1, function(x) order(c(x[1], x[2]))[2])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Dang, this was a tough one :-)

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(r1 = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(rank(input)) < 0)) + 0) %>%
  group_by(r1) %>%
  mutate(r2 = r1 + seq(0, 0.9*(n() < 3), len = n()) / n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(r1 = with(list(rl = rle(r2)$lengths), rep(seq_along(rl), times = rl))) %>%
  select(-r2)
# # A tibble: 13 x 3
#    input   output    r1
#    <chr>    <dbl> <int>
#  1 xx1          1     1
#  2 1xxx         2     2
#  3 abc.xyz      3     3
#  4 a            4     4
#  5 ad022        4     4
#  6 ghj1         4     4
#  7 kf1          4     4
#  8 991r         5     5
#  9 jdd          6     6
# 10 12vd         7     7
# 11 r34o         7     7
# 12 z            7     7
# 13 034mh        8     8
```

(The lengthy `with(...)` in the `mutate` is just an inline version of `data.table::rleid`.)

### `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[
, r1 := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(rank(input)) < 0)) + 0 ][
, r1 := r1 + seq(0, 0.9*(.N < 3), len = .N), by = .(r1) ][
, r1 := rleid(r1) ]
```

If you want to blur the lines of R-dialects a little, then

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
as.data.table(df) %>%
  .[, r1 := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(rank(input)) < 0)) + 0 ] %>%
  .[, r1 := r1 + seq(0, 0.9*(.N < 3), len = .N), by = .(r1) ] %>%
  .[, r1 := rleid(r1) ]
```

---

Notes:

- **`... + 0` is short-hand for `as.numeric(...)`**. This is because `data.table` enforces the column's original `class` when updating a column; since the first definition of `r1` (without `+0`) would be `integer`, the next reassignment of `r1` returns `numeric`. However, since `data.table` persists the original class, the numbers will be coerced (`trunc`ated) to integer and my efforts halted.
- `seq(0, 0.9*(...))` reduces to `seq(0,0)` when there are three or more in a group, which results in a no-op on that group. (This uses `dplyr`'s `n()` and `data.table`'s `.N` for group-size.)
- the implementations differ slightly because `dplyr` prohibits modifying the grouping variable(s); `data.table` has no issue with this. (I'm not certain which direction is correct or better ...)

Comment: Wow! This is smart! Thank you, r2evans. Wondering why do you need `+0` in the first mutate line?

Comment: Yeah, that's a small kludge ... `data.table` enforces class, so without it `r1` is `integer`. In the next row, because I'm doing things *by row*, the return value there will be `numeric` which is different-enough from `integer` that `data.table` complains (and fails). This is safe, and I agree with its (`data.table`) logic and intent (`ifelse` is a great base-R example that violates this safety). So `+0` was another shortcut for wrapping the whole line in `as.numeric(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Not nearly as good as r2evans', but also seems to give the result.

```
x <- my_strings
n <- length(x)
c(FALSE,x[-1L] > x[-n]) &
c(FALSE,FALSE,x[-1L][-1L] > x[-n][-(n-1)]) &
c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,x[-1L][-1L][-1L] > x[-n][-(n-1)][-(n-2)])

(lead(x, 1) > x & lead(x,2) > lead(x,1)) |
  (lag(x, 1) < x & lead(x,1) > x) |
  (lag(x, 1) < x & lag(x,2) < lag(x,1)) -> condition

condition[is.na(condition)] <- FALSE # remove NAs

#to visualize
tibble(lag(x,2), lag(x,1), x, lead(x,1), lead(x,2), condition)

# There may be a better way than a loop
cur_class <- 0
classes <- integer(n)
for(i in 1:(n)){
  if(!condition[i]){ #not in a sequence
    cur_class <- cur_class + 1
    classes[i] <- cur_class
  } else if(!condition[i-1]){ #first of a sequence
    cur_class <- cur_class + 1
    classes[i] <- cur_class
  } else{ #mid-sequence
    classes[i] <- cur_class
  }
}

tibble(x, classes, condition*1L)

# A tibble: 13 x 3
#   x       classes `condition * 1L`
#  <chr>     <dbl>            <int>
# 1 xx1           1                0
# 2 1xxx          2                0
# 3 abc.xyz       3                0
# 4 a             4                1
# 5 ad022         4                1
# 6 ghj1          4                1
# 7 kf1           4                1
# 8 991r          5                0
# 9 jdd           6                0
# 10 12vd          7                1
# 11 r34o          7                1
# 12 z             7                1
# 13 034mh         8                0
```